# How can i list the files from DDMS?

Tags: android, file, ddms

I've some files in this location `data/data/com.android/file/...`   I'm having one listview and one button in my layout and am extends `Activity` only. How can i fetch those files from DDMS and display that by items. Anyone know this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that `com.android` is your package name. If that is the case, you access these files by doing the following

```
String [] files = fileList();
```

[fileList()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#fileList%28%29) is an existing method for your activity so you don't have to write it. This will return to you a list of all private files associated with your application because `/data/data/<package name>/files/...` is where the application saves your private files.

To populate the listView, I would follow the guide here: [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)

That tutorial explains exactly how to create a list view using a String array. So where you have the line

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));
```

Substitute **COUNTRIES** with **files**.

Hope that helps out.

Comment: I'm extending Activity. So, how can i change this example to Activity.

Comment: You extend ListActivity instead as ListActivity is a subclass of Activity.

Comment: I used your method. My list are shown empty. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Ya, it's working fine. Sorry, I'd give the list as invisible so that i can't see anything. Now, it's working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
ArrayList<String> list_files = fileList();



private ArrayList<String> fileList(){

private ArrayList<String> filesList=new ArrayList<String>();

      File dir=new File("data/data/com.android/file");

      File[] files=dir.listFiles();

     for(File f:files){
           filesList.add(f.getName());      
       }

 }
```

then use list view and adapter class to list these arraylist file names in usual way.